# xna - Render background and multiple sprites to a single texture

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, rendering

I currently creating a game and I am trying to render my background  and a sprite to a texture.

Currently I have the background being rendered to a texture. But I am needing to render both my background and another sprite to a single texture. 
Thanks in advance.

```
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Effect blur;
    Texture2D background;
    Texture2D bubble;
    Rectangle bubbleRectangle;
    RenderTarget2D target;
    private Effect blurMapEffect;

    Texture2D attack;
    Rectangle attackRec;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        //{
        // graphics.PreferredDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8;
        // };
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        // target = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
        blurMapEffect = Content.Load<Effect>("blurMapEffect");
        blurMapEffect.Parameters["BlurPower"].SetValue(0.55f);
        blur = Content.Load<Effect>("blur");


        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");

        attack = Content.Load<Texture2D>("attack1");
        attackRec = new Rectangle(50, 100, attack.Width, attack.Height);

        bubble = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bubble - Blue13");
        bubbleRectangle = new Rectangle(250, 250, bubble.Width, bubble.Height);

        target = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            bubbleRectangle.X--;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            bubbleRectangle.X++;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            bubbleRectangle.Y--;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            bubbleRectangle.Y++;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(target);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, blurMapEffect);
        spriteBatch.Draw(bubble, bubbleRectangle, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        blur.Parameters["BlurMapTexture"].SetValue(target);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, blur);
        spriteBatch.Draw(background, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(attack, attackRec, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(bubble, bubbleRectangle, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply draw your sprite before the call to `GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);`

Comment: Great, that seems to work.